# How to return an object from an objects function - javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like below

```
 function obj() {

     this.cellSize = 50;

     this.createBlock = function() { // creates a block object
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0 - (this.cellSize * 1.5);
        this.baseVelocity = 1;
        this.velocity = this.baseVelocity;
        return this;
    };

    this.activeBlock = this.createBlock(); // active block object

    this.nextBlock = this.createBlock(); // next block object
 }
```

When I check `obj.activeBlock` I am not getting the object which should be returned from `obj.createBlock`?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using `new` keyword? `var a = new obj(); console.log(a.activeBlock);`.

Comment: Yes I am but `obj.activeBlock` is the same as `obj`, rather than the object having what is outlined in `createBlock`?

Comment: *"When I check `obj.activeBlock`..."* Seems you're guessing at how `this` in JavaScript works.

Comment: @thesystem I am not guessing just trying to understand, I have only been learning for 2 days

Comment: @ShaShads: Alright, well there's no assignment of `.activeBlock` to `obj`. The `obj` is a function, and `this` isn't a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
function obj() {
     var that = this;
     this.cellSize = 50;

     this.createBlock = function() { // creates a block object
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0 - (that.cellSize * 1.5);
        this.baseVelocity = 1;
        this.velocity = this.baseVelocity;
        return this;
    };

    this.activeBlock = new this.createBlock(); // active block object

    this.nextBlock = new this.createBlock(); // next block object
}
```

The `this` in the `createBlock` function should be different from the `this` of `obj()`. You also need to create a new object using `new` for each block. If `cellSize` is supposed to be a constant, you can rewrite the code as a closure:

```
function obj() {
     var cellSize = 50;

     this.createBlock = function() { // creates a block object
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0 - (cellSize * 1.5);
        this.baseVelocity = 1;
        this.velocity = this.baseVelocity;
        return this;
    };

    this.activeBlock = new this.createBlock(); // active block object

    this.nextBlock = new this.createBlock(); // next block object
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly where I was going wrong, thanks for the closure tip :)

Comment: @TedHopp: If OP did that, the function would no longer have access to the variable scope being used in your answer. And since `.createBlock` is invoked as a constructor, it also wouldn't have access to any properties of the object on which it was invoked.

Comment: @thesystem - Yeah, I just realized that. Best would be a factory function rather than a constructor. Deleting the comment.